# Is there anyway to use toggle() of jquery dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Edited:

I want to make a div that it has some divs inside of it. and I want to toggle that divs and when I click on one of buttons I want to disappear not matched divs and appear matched div .This is my code:

```
<div class="TheToggle">
    <button id="Toggle1">Toggle 1</button>
    <button id="Toggle2">Toggle 2</button>
    <button id="Toggle2">Toggle 3</button>


    <div class="Toggle1">This 1</div>
    <div class="Toggle2">This 2</div>
    <div class="Toggle3">This 3</div>
</div>
```

Actually at the first I want to display Toggle1 content and when I click on another buttons I wanna appear the div of that button and disappear another one.

Comment: Are you saying that you want the buttons to toggle their respective div elements, and hide any other divs that do not match?

Comment: Also, please provide any attempt you have made to do this yourself.  Question are expected to show an attempt, to ensure people are not just asking for answers without making an effort first.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: @Tapler Yeah, I want the buttons when I click on one of them I want to appear the matched content and disappear another ones...

Comment: So you're wanting to happen when a button is *clicked*, and you have an id on the buttons that ties into the classes of the divs.  Do you have any ideas on how you might do this?

Comment: @Taplar Yeah Give the class of display block and give the display none to another. I don't know how to do that

Comment: Sounds like you are fairly shaky on the basics of jQuery.  I would highly suggest you take some time to read over https://learn.jquery.com .  It includes many of the basics, including manipulating selections and creating event bindings

Comment: @Taplar Sure Tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.TheToggle button');

buttons.forEach(b => {
 b.addEventListener('click', () => {
        document.querySelectorAll('.TheToggle > div')
         .forEach(d => d.style.display = 'none');
   document.querySelector(`[data-hide="${b.getAttribute('id')}"]`).style.display = 'block';
  }) 
});
```

```html
<div class="TheToggle">
    <button id="Toggle1">Toggle 1</button>
    <button id="Toggle2">Toggle 2</button>
    <button id="Toggle3">Toggle 3</button>


    <div data-hide="Toggle1">This 1</div>
    <div data-hide="Toggle2">This 2</div>
    <div data-hide="Toggle3">This 3</div>
</div>
```